# Can I use a view bound in a Scala value class?

Tags: scala, generics

While dealing with some Java code, I wanted to find a way to reduce a Raw Set to include its parameterized type.

I also wanted it to work for Scala sets as well, so I did the following

```
implicit class Harden[S <% mutable.Set[_]](val set: S) extends AnyVal {
    def cast[T] = set.map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

That resulted in a compiler error that I didn't expect

```
Error:(27, 27) field definition is not allowed in value class
  implicit class Harden[S <% mutable.Set[_]](val set: S) extends AnyVal {
```

I didn't find any mention of this type of restriction in the Scala View Bounds or Value Class documentation.

Why is this not allowed? I'm using Scala 2.10.3.

Comment: I think view bound (`<%`) is going to be deprecated from 2.12. Just so you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from this *sbt console* output:

```
scala> :type implicit class Harden[S <% mutable.Set[_]](val set: S)
[S]AnyRef {
  val set: S
  private[this] val set: S
  implicit private[this] val evidence$1: S => scala.collection.mutable.Set[_]
  def <init>(set: S)(implicit evidence$1: S => scala.collection.mutable.Set[_]): Harden[S]
}
```

... the actual constructor of `Harden` desugars behind the scenes to:

```
def <init>(set: S)(implicit evidence$1: S => scala.collection.mutable.Set[_]): Harden[S]
```

... (i.e. takes `set` in one argument list and implicit `evidence$1` in another).

As described in value classes limitations [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

> must have only a primary constructor with exactly one public, val parameter whose type is not a value class.

... whitch means that `Harden` violaties this limitation.

You can achieve something similar, howerver. Try to convert your view bound defined on class to implicit evidence on method instead.

Something like this:

```
scala> implicit class Harden[S](val set: S) extends AnyVal {
     |     def cast[T](implicit ev: S => scala.collection.mutable.Set[_]) = set.map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
     | }
defined class Harden
```

This will compile:

```
scala> Set(1,2,3).cast[Any]
res17: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Any] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

And this will fail, as expected:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).cast[Any]
<console>:24: error: No implicit view available from List[Int] => scala.collection.mutable.Set[_].
              List(1,2,3).cast[Any]
                              ^
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed because as structured now, value classes must have exactly one parameter, but

```
implicit class Foo[A <% B](val a: A)
```

desugars to

```
implicit class Foo[A,B](val a: A)(implicit evidence$1: A => B)
```

which no longer has just a single parameter.